# GiantBomb API Work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, search

I have made an account and have my api key currently i just want a simple search box and button that when hit will list the game and the image of that game

Have linked the site info below

http://www.giantbomb.com/api/documentation

I want to run is and get the output using json and jquery any help welcome

This is a working search now some what does not allow the user to enter in a new value and there is a problem bring up the image

two main problems wont load the image just says undefined and cant figure out how to make it a full search only when he user enters a new title

```
   <html>
      <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
              url: "http://api.giantbomb.com/search/",
              type: "get",
              data: {api_key : "key here", query: "star trek", resources : "game", field_list : "name, resource_type, image", format : "jsonp", json_callback : "gamer" },
              dataType: "jsonp"
            });
    });

    function gamer(data) {
              var table = '<table>';
              $.each( data.results, function( key, value ) {
              table += '<tr><td>' + value.image + '</td><td>' + value.name + '</td><td>' + value.resource_type + '</td></tr>';
            });
                table += '</table>';
            $('#myelement').html(table);
    }

        </script>

      </head>
      <body>
      <h1>Game Search</h1>
      <input id="game" type="text" /><button id="search">Search</button>
      <div id="myelement"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your working code as per standard of the giantbomb docs:

```
var apikey = "My key";
var baseUrl = "http://www.giantbomb.com/api";

// construct the uri with our apikey
var GamesSearchUrl = baseUrl + '/search/?api_key=' + apikey + '&format=json';
var query = "Batman";

$(document).ready(function() {

  // send off the query
  $.ajax({
    url: GamesSearchUrl + '&query=' + encodeURI(query),
    dataType: "json",
    success: searchCallback
  });


    // callback for when we get back the results
    function searchCallback(data) {
        $('body').append('Found ' + data.total + ' results for ' + query);
        var games = data.game;
        $.each(games, function(index, game) {
            $('body').append('<h1>' + game.name + '</h1>');
            $('body').append('<p>' + game.description + '</p>');
            $('body').append('<img src="' + game.posters.thumbnail + '" />');
        });
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LGqD3/

## GiantBomb Api example/explanation

### First get your api key

Key: http://www.giantbomb.com/api/
Documentation: http://www.giantbomb.com/api/documentation

#### Your base url:

`http://www.giantbomb.com/api/`

#### Your url structure:

`/RESOURCE?api_key=[YOUR_API_KEY]&format=json/FILTERS/FIELDS`

- `/RESOURCE/ID` example: /game/3030-38206/
  The type of resource you which to return, in your case a search. Sometimes.. in case of a specific game you also want to pass in the ID under `/ID` (like in the example)
- `api_key`
  Your api key
  You need this otherwise you cannot use the api :)
- `format`
  The format you which to output, in this case json.
- `FILTERS` example: /search?limit=100
  This manipulates the resourses output
  See under the resources in the documentation for a what you can do.
- `FIELDS` example: /search?field_list=description,
  Which field to return, use this to "reduce the size of the response payload"

#### A game request for it's name & description would be:

`http://www.giantbomb.com/api/game/3030-38206/?api_key=[YOUR-API-KEY]&format=json&field_list=name,description`

#### A search request

Lets say we want to search for the game "Elder scroll online".
You would construct your url like this:
`/search/?api_key=[YOUR-API-KEY]&format=json&query="elder scrolls online"&resources=game`

### To implement this in with $.ajax:

#### The ajax function

```
/*
 *  Send a get request to the Giant bomb api.
 *  @param string resource set the RESOURCE.
 *  @param object data specifiy any filters or fields.
 *  @param object callbacks specify any custom callbacks.
 */
function sendRequest(resource, data, callbacks) {
    var baseURL = 'http://giantbomb.com/api';
    var apiKey = '[YOUR-API-KEY]';
    var format = 'json';

    // make sure data is an empty object if its not defined.
    data = data || {};

    // Proccess the data, the ajax function escapes any characters like ,
    // So we need to send the data with the "url:"
    var str, tmpArray = [], filters;
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        str = key + '=' + value;
        tmpArray.push(str);
    });

    // Create the filters if there were any, else it's an empty string.
    filters =  (tmpArray.length > 0) ? '&' + tmpArray.join('&') : '';

    // Create the request url.
    var requestURL = baseURL + resource + "?api_key=" + apiKey + "&format=" + format + filters;

    // Set custom callbacks if there are any, otherwise use the default onces.
    // Explanation: if callbacks.beforesend is passend in the argument callbacks, then use it. 
    // If not "||"" set an default function.
    var callbacks = callbacks || {};
    callbacks.beforeSend = callbacks.beforeSend || function(response) {};
    callbacks.success = callbacks.success || function(response) {};
    callbacks.error = callbacks.error || function(response) {};
    callbacks.complete = callbacks.complete || function(response) {};

    // the actual ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: requestURL,
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',

        // Callback methods,
        beforeSend: function() {
            callbacks.beforeSend()
        },
        success: function(response) {
            callbacks.success(response);
        },
        error: function(response) {
            callbacks.error(response);
        },
        complete: function() {
            callbacks.complete();
        }
    });
}
```

#### search function

```
function search() {
    // Get your text box input, something like: 
    // You might want to put a validate and sanitation function before sending this to the ajax function.
    var searchString = $('.textox').val();

    // Set the fields or filters 
    var data = {
        query: searchString,
        resources: 'game'
    };

    // Send the ajax request with to '/search' resource and with custom callbacks
    sendRequest('/search', data, { 
        // Custom callbacks, define here what you want the search callbacks to do when fired.
        beforeSend: function(data) {},
        success: function(data) {},
        error: function(data) {},
        complete: function(data) {},
    });
}
```

#### Example of a get game function

```
function getGame() {
    // get game id from somewhere like a link.
    var gameID = '3030-38206';
    var resource = '/game/' + gameID;

    // Set the fields or filters 
    var data = {
        field_list: 'name,description'
    };

    // No custom callbacks defined here, just use the default onces.
    sendRequest(resource, data);
}
```

#### EDIT: you could also make a mini api wrapper out of this, something like:

```
var apiWrapper = {};

apiWrapper.request = function(resource, data, callbacks) {
    // The get function;
};

apiWrapper.search = function(data) {
    // The search function
};

apiWrapper.getGame = function(id, data) {
    // The game function
}

apiWrapper.init = function(config) {
    var config = config || {};
    this.apiKey = config.apiKey || false;
    this.baseURL = config.baseURL || 'http://api.giantbomb.com';
}

apiWrapper.init({
    apiKey: '[API-KEY]'
});
```

Have not tested the code, so there might be a bug in it, will clean it up tommorow :)
Edit: fixed a bug in $.ajax

Comment: tryed the fiddle and added in my key and changed the base url no results came up i have posted the errors from the console above

Comment: @Jamiex304 are you using jsFiddle? you cannot use ajax request on JSfiddle to other sites, try it in your own code.

Comment: im still getting this error when running it XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.giantbomb.com/api//search/?api_key=516f7cff88df5d3a5e493a40dcc8499f663e667ea&format=json&query=Batman. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: try `dataType: jsonp`

Comment: now i am getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : i ahve updated my answer with my code so far

Comment: @Jamiex304 make sure you don't have two slashes in your url `api//search` `api/search`, and dont use JSFiddle for testing ajax. :)

Comment: im not using the jsfiddle for texting and i have post the code i am using above no double slashes

Comment: @Jamiex304 I saw a small mistake in my code, try again. I've been too long on the code, eyes straining :P
And what line is that error on? i've tested the code in a jshint no errors there. must be in the ajax response?

Comment: sry but im still no getting any results to come up i have post the error i keep getting above im almost ready to start again at this point this is so much more complicted than using the omdb api lol

Comment: @Jamiex304 yeah i thought so, jsonp is not supported afterall. it fixed the cross domain error but gives this.
Best thing what you can do switch back to `dataType: 'json'`, if you get the cross domain error, make sure you are not testing from a `file://` in your browser but from a localhost server (like xampp). If that does not work look around the giantbomb site and check if you can specify an url where the script is going to be used.

Comment: @Jamiex304 ofcourse, whatever works for you best, happy to have tried to help ! :P

Comment: ok i will give it a shot if u can think of anything that might help or even a basic html example u get working plz post it here but thanks anyways for the help

Comment: was able to get some of what i wanted working still not a search yet and i cant bring in a the image problay any help ?>