# JSON request returning undefined, not an error

Tags: javascript, json, api, jsonp

```
function searchGames(query) {
  // send off the query
  $.ajax({
    url: GamesSearchUrl,
    type : "get",
    data: {
            query : query,
            resources: "game", 
            format: "jsonp", 
            crossDomain: true, 
            limit: 16, 
            field_list : "description,name,image", 
            json_callback : "returnGames",
            sort : "original_release_date:desc"
          },
    dataType: "jsonp"
  });
};
/* Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22918573/giantbomb-api-work */
/* Reference: http://www.giantbomb.com/forums/api-developers-3017/api-request-with-jsonp-uncaught-syntaxerror-1492639/ */

    // callback for when we get back the results
    function returnGames(data) {
      $('div#display').append('Found ' + data.total + ' results for ' + data.query);
      var games = data.game;
        $.each(games, function(index, game) {
            $('div#display').append('<h1>' + game.name + '</h1>');
            $('div#display').append('<p>' + game.description + '</p>');
            $('div#display').append('<img src="' + game.image + '" />');
        });
    }
```

Functions are listed above, as I understand the JSONP data should be passed to the returnGames function, however the output on the page is Found undefined results for undefined. The console shows no errors?

I'm using the giantbomb API. The variables like query and GameSearchURL are defined as global variables at the top of the document. console.log in the function shows the variables have been passed to it correctly.

Comment: what does `console.log(data)` at the top of `returnGames` show